# Cannot italicize words containing an underscore or an asterisk

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

This doesn't work:

- *emphasized_text*
- _emphasized_text_
- *emphasized*text*
- _emphasized*text_

This works:

- <i>*emphasized_text*</i>
- **more_bold**
- **more*bold**

Answer (score 6):

If you want to italicize a word containing an underscore:

*like_this*

`_like\_this_`

If you want to italicize a word containing an asterisk

*like*this*

`_like\*this_`

Answer (score 0):

We do not support intra-word Markdown emphasis. If you need that use HTML tags.

This is by design. For context, see:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/three-markdown-gotcha/

Comment: This is about using special markdown characters inside a word rather than intra-word markdown. You can see in the examples, that it works fine with **bold_text**, just not with *italic_text*.

Comment: *test_test*, *test*test* - oh, it seems to work in the comments. Another indicator, that this is a bug and not by design.